# Does aosp master branch contain future release features?

Tags: android-source

According to the aosp document the future release of Android is developed internally by google: https://source.android.com/setup/code-lines#about-private-code-lines. However if you download the master branch of aosp the code name is already P which is a future release:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
cd [source root]
. ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch 6

PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=P
PLATFORM_VERSION=P
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-17.3.0-x86_64-10.13.2
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OC-DR1
OUT_DIR=out
```

The future release development is not visible to external google developers but what's the role of aosp master branch? How does it fit into the codeline graph shown here: https://source.android.com/setup/code-lines